# How to select partial fields from collection which is of one-to-many relation to the entity in JPQL

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

The question is quite mouthful , it can be simply  described by the following query:

```
select c.name,c.brands FROM ShopChannels c
```

ShopChannel is the basic entity which has a collection of  brands which is of on-to-many,instead select all the brand properties in this query ,I only want to select partial fields of Brand, if I use

```
select c.name,c.brands.spell from ShopChannels c
```

I'll get a "cannot navigate collection valued association field " error message.

This kind of query can greatly boost performance, so anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPA specification says that "´It is syntactically illegal to compose a path expression from a path expression that evaluates to a collection.´"  A solution to your need is a join query like:  ´select c.name,b.spell from ShopChannels c inner join c.brands b´.

Comment: Thanks, but this method has to instantiate the object by hand, and could not use EclipseLink session cache, anyway a good solution.